# Separate class declaration and method definition files problem

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to use separate files for my project, including header file, which declares class methods and .cpp file for defining methods.

But, enforcing hidden method implementation I get errors and can't compile code.

File vector.h

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H


#include <iostream>

class Point
{
private:
    float x;
    float y;

public:
    Point(float x, float y);
    float get_x() const;
    float get_y() const;

};

#endif // VECTOR_H
```

File vector.cpp

```
#include "vector.h"

Point::Point(float x, float y): x(x), y(y) {}

float Point::get_x() const
{
    return x;
}

float Point::get_y() const
{
    return y;
}

Point operator+(Point& pt1, Point& pt2)
{
    return {pt1.get_x() + pt2.get_x(), pt1.get_y() + pt2.get_y()};
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& pt)
{
    os << '(' << pt.get_x() << ', ' << pt.get_y() << ')';
    return os;
}
```

File source.cpp

```
#include "vector.h"

int main()
{
    Point p1(1.4, 2.324), p2(2.004, -4.2345);

    std::cout << p1 << '\n';
    std::cout << p2 << '\n';
    std::cout << p1 + p2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

In the end I get:

```cpp
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'Point')

error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Point' and 'Point')
```

Comment: I don't see the `<<` operator being declared in the header file. Ditto for the `+` operator. It is defined in the `.cpp` file, but the whole purpose of header files is to declare stuff that's defined in header files, so that other translation units know that they exist, right? How do you expect one `.cpp` to know about a custom operator or a function that's defined in another `.cpp`, unless it gets explicitly declared somewhere. Oh, and the operators better take `const` parameters too, otherwise they won't work with temporary objects.

Comment: Missing `const` for `Point operator+(Point& pt1, Point& pt2)`, -> `Point operator+(const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a compile error for your main knows nothing about `operator+` and `operator<<`.

Write

```
Point operator+(Point& pt1, Point& pt2);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& pt);
```

in `h` file or forward declare them in the `main` file.

One more thing. You should use "" in `<< ", " <<`.

Comment: Prefer to add the declarations to the header over placing them directly in main. The header is more useful going forward.

Comment: Why I can't add
`Point operator+(Point& pt1, Point& pt2);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& pt);`
 lines in `public` of class?

Comment: @Pr.Germux, you may. Yet the signature will be different. I'll post an answer in a moment.

Comment: @Pr.Germux, it will be `Point operator+(const Point& lhs) const` for the `operator+`. By the way, make everything which is logically `const` actually `const`.

Comment: @Pr.Germux, for the `operator<<`, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351166/does-overloading-operator-works-inside-the-class